# align left img tag for Internet Explorer, deforms the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have this tag in my html:

```
<img border="0" src="images\Close.gif" alt="بستن" onclick="hideSearchPopUp(id);"/>
```

there is no problem in most known browsers, but in Internet Explorer parent `<div>` tag comes deformed.
like this picture:

[image: deformed parent div tag]

as you can see here, height of parent div increased and close button moved to bottom left

Comment: give access to fiddle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it was a bug of IE!
I was set height for parent, but it does not work until I set width!
after setting width height comes true, as I was set.

```
<div id="banner_div" style="overflow: auto; height: 16px; width: 120px;">
        <strong style=" float:right;">
            جستجو
        </strong>
    <img border="0" src="images\Cancel.gif" alt="بستن" onclick="hideSearchPopUp('to1');" align="left">
    <img border="0" src="images\loading.gif" alt="در حال جستجو" style="display:none;  " align="left" name="loading">
</div>
```